# What is the explanation of negative temperature coefficient in ignition delay of a fuel?

Tags: combustion, mixtures, fuel

When studying the ignition delay of a fuel, some fuel have a negative temperature coefficient area (NTC) where an increase of initial temperature of the mixture air/fuel produces an increase of the ignition delay:

[image: NTC]

What is the explanation of the NTC phenomena? Why does the ignition delay increases when initial temperature increases only for a limited range of temperature? What is happening inside the mixture air/fuel that explains NTC?

Comment: Just speculating - there can be creation of relatively stable radicals on tertiary carbon atoms, scavenging oxygen based radicals, but not keeping pace with them for long.